# most common words between 2 files using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and trying to write script which finds most frequent common words between 2 files. I am able to find most common words between 2 files separately but not sure how to count lets say top 5 words that are common in both the files? Need to find common words and also frequency of those common words between both the files should be most higher as well.

```
import re
from collections import Counter


finalLineLower=''
with open("test3.txt", "r") as hfFile:
        for line in hfFile:
            finalLine = re.sub('[,.<;:)-=!>_(?"]', '', line)            
            finalLineLower += finalLine.lower()
            words1 = finalLineLower.split()

f = open('test2.txt', 'r')
sWords = [line.strip() for line in f]


finalLineLower1=''
with open("test4.txt", "r") as tsFile:
        for line in tsFile:
            finalLine = re.sub('[,.<;:)-=!>_(?"]', '', line)            
            finalLineLower1 += finalLine.lower()
            words = finalLineLower1.split()
#print (words)
mc = Counter(words).most_common()
mc2 = Counter(words1).most_common()

print(len(mc))
print(len(mc2))
```

Example test3 and test4 files are as below.
test3:

```
Essays are generally scholarly pieces of writing giving the author's own argument, but the definition is vague, overlapping with those of an article, a pamphlet and a short story.
```

test4:

```
Essays are generally scholarly pieces of writing giving the author's own argument, but the definition is vague, overlapping with those of an article, a pamphlet and a short story.

Essays can consist of a number of elements, including: literary criticism, political manifestos, learned arguments, observations of daily life, recollections, and reflections of the author. Almost all modern essays are written in prose, but works in verse have been dubbed essays (e.g. Alexander Pope's An Essay on Criticism and An Essay on Man). While brevity usually defines an essay, voluminous works like John Locke's An Essay Concerning Human Understanding and Thomas Malthus's An Essay on the Principle of Population are counterexamples. In some countries (e.g., the United States and Canada), essays have become a major part of formal education. Secondary students are taught structured essay formats to improve their writing skills, and admission essays are often used by universities in selecting applicants and, in the humanities and social sciences, as a way of assessing the performance of students during final exams.
```

Comment: How do you define this? Say "hello" appears 100,000 times in the first file, and 1 time in the second file, is it more or less common that "goodbye" which appears 500 times in each?

Comment: Why have you tagged this both `python-2.7` and `python-3.x`? Do you specifically need code that works in both versions? And that works _the same_, even in the presence of non-ASCII characters, in both versions? Because if so, you have to change some stuff that isn't relevant to your question but is very relevant to your code working (e.g., explicitly open the files in binary mode and `decode` the strings, then use Unicode string literals for your regexps).

Comment: If "hello" appears 100,000 times in first file and 1 time on second than it is common for both and highest in terms of frequency as well so it will appear first on the result of top 5 common words. So basically find top 5 words that are highest frequency and is inside both the files.

Comment: @abarnet, I am OK if code work only on Python 2.7 which is running on my machine right now. Let me remove the other tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply find the intersection between your `Counter` objects with `&` operand :

```
mc = Counter(words)
mc2 = Counter(words1)
total=mc&mc2
mos=total.most_common(N)
```

Example :

```
>>> d1={'a':5,'f':2,'c':1,'h':2,'t':4}
>>> d2={'a':3,'b':2,'e':1,'h':5,'t':6}
>>> c1=Counter(d1)
>>> c2=Counter(d2)
>>> t=c1&c2
>>> t
Counter({'t': 4, 'a': 3, 'h': 2})
>>> t.most_common(2)
[('t', 4), ('a', 3)]
```

But Note that `&` returns the minimum Count between your Counters you can also use union `|` that returns the maximum Counts and you can use a simple dict comprehension to get the max counts :

```
>>> m=c1|c2
>>> m
Counter({'t': 6, 'a': 5, 'h': 5, 'b': 2, 'f': 2, 'c': 1, 'e': 1})
>>> max={i:j for i,j in m.items() if i in t}
>>> max
{'a': 5, 'h': 5, 't': 6}
```

And at last if you want the sum of common words you can add your Counters together :

```
>>> s=Counter(max)+t
>>> s
Counter({'t': 10, 'a': 8, 'h': 7})
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it is throwing me error as     total=mc&mc2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'. how to resolve that?

Comment: @user3314492 Welcome, In your question `mc` and `mc2` are counter but your error says they are list. you need to do `mc = Counter(words)` and `mc2 = Counter(words2)`

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine now. Thank you for your help again. I was doing it wrong and was trying to join list by getting most_common on both counter separately.

Answer (score 1):

This question is ambiguous.

You could be asking for the words that are most common among the two files together—so, e.g., a word that appears 10000 times in file1 and 1 time in file2 counts as appearing 10001 times. In that case:

```
mc = Counter(words) + Counter(words1) # or Counter(chain(words, words1))
mos = mc.most_common(5)
```

Or you could be asking for the words that are most common in *either* file, that also appear at least once in the other file:

```
mc = Counter(words)
mc1 = Counter(words1)
mcmerged = Counter({word: max(mc[word], mc1[word]) for word in mc if word in mc1})
mos = mcmerged.most_common(5)
```

Or the most common among the two files together, but only if they also appear at least once in each file:

```
mc = Counter(words)
mc1 = Counter(words1)
mcmerged = Counter({word: mc[word] + mc1[word] for word in mc if word in mc1})
```

There are probably other ways this could be interpreted as well. If you can phrase the rule in unambiguous English, it should be pretty easy to translate it to Python; if you can't do so, it will be impossible.

---

From your comments, it sounds like you're not actually reading the code in this answer, and trying to use your `mc = Counter(words).most_common()` instead of the `mc = Counter(words)` or `mc = Counter(words) + Counter(words1)`, etc. in this answer. When you call `most_common()` on a `Counter`, you get back a `list`, not a `Counter`. Just… don't do that, do the code that's actually here.

Comment: It is throwing me error when I try to get the most common again after summation. What should I do there? mos=total.most_common(10)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'most_common'

Comment: @user3314492: Then you're not running the code I gave you, because `Counter(words) + Counter(words1)` is going to return a `Counter`, not a `list`.

Comment: It is working fine now. Thank you. I was doing it wrong earlier and was still doing counter.most_common and than sum. It works now.